Unable to update test result configuration via Azure DevOps API
Trying to update "configuration" field in test result using Azure API but it is not updating (except of other fields).
Steps:

create test run. each result gets some default configuration.
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/runs?api-version=7.2-preview.3
update results different fields, also with "configuration"
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/results?api-version=7.2-preview.6
body:

[
    {
        "id": 100000,
        "configuration": {
            "id": "242",
            "name": "Windows - Chrome",
            "url": "https://dev.azure.com/<some>/<some>/_apis/test/Configurations/242"
        },
        "project": {
            "id": "3d2c2537-dde1-4cf9-8d84-561605d38614",
            "name": "some",
            "url": "https://dev.azure.com/<some>/_apis/projects/some"
        },
        "startedDate": "2024-12-19T17:41:08.579000Z",
        "completedDate": "2024-12-19T17:41:22.120000Z",
        "revision": 1,
        "state": "Completed",
..........
...........
]

Result: fields are updated except "configuration".
What can be wrong?
